# How can I have my google play app support more devices?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

I have recently published my first app on to the Google Play store, but since I am quite new to programming I am unsure of what to do to fix the problems that I currently have.
You see, the Google Play console tells me that only 2006 devices are supported by the app, even though I don't see a reason why that is.

Settings and stuff:
I have used Unity and C# to create the app. In the unity engine, under build settings, I have set the minimum API level to 19, and the target API to automatic (highest installed).
Originally, I just let Unity create the manifest file for the game, but to try and fix my problem I created a new manifest file. I placed it in the assets, in a folder named android, which is in a folder named plugins (some tutorial told me to do that). The Manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN-->
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
    <supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
        
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have published the app to the Google Play store, but on all devices except 2006 it just says

> This version is incompatible with your device

Does anyone have any idea of how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Also, I should mention that I sent an email to the Google Play developer support and I got this response:

> Hi there,
>
> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support.
>
> I understand you're trying to figure out why your device, the Samsung
> Galaxy Note9, is not compatible with your app.  I've checked some
> things on my end and see that the following versions of the device are
> incompatible for the following reasons:
>
> Galaxy Note9 running Android SDK 29:
>
> No supported GL Textures: GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture,
> GL_AMD_performance_monitor, GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a,
> GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object,
> GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_EGL_image_array,
> GL_EXT_EGL_image_external_wrap_modes, GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage,
> GL_EXT_YUV_target, GL_EXT_blend_func_extended,
> GL_EXT_blit_framebuffer_params, GL_EXT_buffer_storage,
> GL_EXT_clip_control, GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance,
> GL_EXT_color_buffer_float, GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float,
> GL_EXT_copy_image, GL_EXT_debug_label, GL_EXT_debug_marker,
> GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query,
> GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_EXT_external_buffer,
> GL_EXT_fragment_invocation_density, GL_EXT_geometry_shader,
> GL_EXT_gpu_shader5, GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd,
> GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture,
> GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2, GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box,
> GL_EXT_protected_textures, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, GL_EXT_robustness,
> GL_EXT_sRGB, GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control,
> GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch, GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks,
> GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers,
> GL_EXT_tessellation_shader, GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp,
> GL_EXT_texture_buffer, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array,
> GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888,
> GL_EXT_texture_format_sRGB_override, GL_EXT_texture_norm16,
> GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
> GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced,
> GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent, GL_KHR_debug,
> GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior,
> GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr,
> GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
> GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation, GL_OES_EGL_image,
> GL_OES_EGL_image_external, GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3,
> GL_OES_EGL_sync, GL_OES_blend_equation_separate,
> GL_OES_blend_func_separate, GL_OES_blend_subtract,
> GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture,
> GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture, GL_OES_depth24,
> GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map,
> GL_OES_draw_texture, GL_OES_element_index_uint,
> GL_OES_framebuffer_object, GL_OES_get_program_binary,
> GL_OES_matrix_palette, GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil,
> GL_OES_point_size_array, GL_OES_point_sprite, GL_OES_read_format,
> GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_sample_shading, GL_OES_sample_variables,
> GL_OES_shader_image_atomic, GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation,
> GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_stencil_wrap,
> GL_OES_surfaceless_context, GL_OES_texture_3D,
> GL_OES_texture_compression_astc, GL_OES_texture_cube_map,
> GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar, GL_OES_texture_float,
> GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float,
> GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat,
> GL_OES_texture_npot, GL_OES_texture_stencil8,
> GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array, GL_OES_texture_view,
> GL_OES_vertex_array_object, GL_OES_vertex_half_float,
> GL_OVR_multiview, GL_OVR_multiview2,
> GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture,
> GL_QCOM_YUV_texture_gather, GL_QCOM_alpha_test, GL_QCOM_extended_get,
> GL_QCOM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_noncoherent,
> GL_QCOM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_rate, GL_QCOM_texture_foveated,
> GL_QCOM_texture_foveated_subsampled_layout, GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
>
> Galaxy Note9 running Android SDK 27: The app supports SDK 29+ only, so
> no device running an SDK under 29 can install the app.  However, this
> version also does not support GL textures (note that this is a
> different set than the set above):
>
> GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture, GL_AMD_performance_monitor,
> GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a, GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot,
> GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object,
> GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_EGL_image_array,
> GL_EXT_YUV_target, GL_EXT_blit_framebuffer_params,
> GL_EXT_buffer_storage, GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance,
> GL_EXT_color_buffer_float, GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float,
> GL_EXT_copy_image, GL_EXT_debug_label, GL_EXT_debug_marker,
> GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query,
> GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_EXT_external_buffer,
> GL_EXT_geometry_shader, GL_EXT_gpu_shader5, GL_EXT_memory_object,
> GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture,
> GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2, GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box,
> GL_EXT_protected_textures, GL_EXT_robustness, GL_EXT_sRGB,
> GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control, GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch,
> GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks,
> GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers,
> GL_EXT_tessellation_shader, GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp,
> GL_EXT_texture_buffer, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array,
> GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888,
> GL_EXT_texture_norm16, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8,
> GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV,
> GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced,
> GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent, GL_KHR_debug,
> GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr,
> GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
> GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation, GL_OES_EGL_image,
> GL_OES_EGL_image_external, GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3,
> GL_OES_EGL_sync, GL_OES_blend_equation_separate,
> GL_OES_blend_func_separate, GL_OES_blend_subtract,
> GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture,
> GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture, GL_OES_depth24,
> GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map,
> GL_OES_draw_texture, GL_OES_element_index_uint,
> GL_OES_framebuffer_object, GL_OES_get_program_binary,
> GL_OES_matrix_palette, GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil,
> GL_OES_point_size_array, GL_OES_point_sprite, GL_OES_read_format,
> GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_sample_shading, GL_OES_sample_variables,
> GL_OES_shader_image_atomic, GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation,
> GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_stencil_wrap,
> GL_OES_surfaceless_context, GL_OES_texture_3D,
> GL_OES_texture_compression_astc, GL_OES_texture_cube_map,
> GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar, GL_OES_texture_float,
> GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float,
> GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat,
> GL_OES_texture_npot, GL_OES_texture_stencil8,
> GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array,
> GL_OES_vertex_array_object, GL_OES_vertex_half_float,
> GL_OVR_multiview, GL_OVR_multiview2,
> GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture, GL_QCOM_alpha_test,
> GL_QCOM_extended_get, GL_QCOM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_noncoherent,
> GL_QCOM_texture_foveated, GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
>
> Galaxy Note9 running Android 28: Again, devices running any SDK lower
> than 29 are not compatible with the app.  However, this version of
> this device is also incompatible due to no supported GL textures
> (which is a different set than either of the two above):
>
> GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture, GL_AMD_performance_monitor,
> GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a, GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot,
> GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object,
> GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_EGL_image_array,
> GL_EXT_EGL_image_external_wrap_modes, GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage,
> GL_EXT_YUV_target, GL_EXT_blend_func_extended,
> GL_EXT_blit_framebuffer_params, GL_EXT_buffer_storage,
> GL_EXT_clip_control, GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance,
> GL_EXT_color_buffer_float, GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float,
> GL_EXT_copy_image, GL_EXT_debug_label, GL_EXT_debug_marker,
> GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query,
> GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_EXT_external_buffer,
> GL_EXT_geometry_shader, GL_EXT_gpu_shader5, GL_EXT_memory_object,
> GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture,
> GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2, GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box,
> GL_EXT_protected_textures, GL_EXT_robustness, GL_EXT_sRGB,
> GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control, GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch,
> GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks,
> GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers,
> GL_EXT_tessellation_shader, GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp,
> GL_EXT_texture_buffer, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array,
> GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888,
> GL_EXT_texture_format_sRGB_override, GL_EXT_texture_norm16,
> GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
> GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced,
> GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent, GL_KHR_debug,
> GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior,
> GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr,
> GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
> GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation, GL_OES_EGL_image,
> GL_OES_EGL_image_external, GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3,
> GL_OES_EGL_sync, GL_OES_blend_equation_separate,
> GL_OES_blend_func_separate, GL_OES_blend_subtract,
> GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture,
> GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture, GL_OES_depth24,
> GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map,
> GL_OES_draw_texture, GL_OES_element_index_uint,
> GL_OES_framebuffer_object, GL_OES_get_program_binary,
> GL_OES_matrix_palette, GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil,
> GL_OES_point_size_array, GL_OES_point_sprite, GL_OES_read_format,
> GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_sample_shading, GL_OES_sample_variables,
> GL_OES_shader_image_atomic, GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation,
> GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_stencil_wrap,
> GL_OES_surfaceless_context, GL_OES_texture_3D,
> GL_OES_texture_compression_astc, GL_OES_texture_cube_map,
> GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar, GL_OES_texture_float,
> GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float,
> GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat,
> GL_OES_texture_npot, GL_OES_texture_stencil8,
> GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array,
> GL_OES_vertex_array_object, GL_OES_vertex_half_float,
> GL_OVR_multiview, GL_OVR_multiview2,
> GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture, GL_QCOM_alpha_test,
> GL_QCOM_extended_get, GL_QCOM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_noncoherent,
> GL_QCOM_texture_foveated, GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
>
> We can't tell you what to do about GL textures as we aren't trained on
> app development, so  you may want to check with a public developers
> forum, such as the one at stackoverflow.com
>
> To resolve the Android SDK issue, you would need to alter your app's
> manifest so that the minSDK value is lower.
>
> I hope this helps!  Please let me know if you have other questions or
> concerns.
>
> Regards Pete Google Play Developer Support

Comment: Your manifest still has the line that allows Unity to overwrite it. There is no minSDK value set in it. I would recommend using APKTool https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ to unpack your APK file and look at the full manifest.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I did what you told me and the generated manifest file has these lines of code:                                                                                                       
       <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

Comment: Are your textures compressed as ETC/ETC2?

Comment: @RetiredNinja under build settings "PVRTC (PowerVR)" is chosen for the texture compression. Under that there is also "ETC2 fallback" which is set to 32-bit.

Comment: That may be your problem. You should read the Android section here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterOverride.html#notes-on-android You probably want to set that to ETC2 or Don't override.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I created a new build of the game with ETC2. I will tell you later if it fixed the issue when I can see how many devices that the new build can support :D

Comment: @RetiredNinja Man thank you so much!!!! Switching the texture compression fixed the issue. The supported devices shot up from 2k to 9k! I can't thank you enough :D Have a really good day <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @RetiredNinja for solving the issue! This is what he wrote (idk how to accept a reply as the answer):

"Are your textures compressed as ETC/ETC2? – Retired Ninja"

"That may be your problem. You should read the Android section here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterOverride.html#notes-on-android You probably want to set that to ETC2 or Don't override. – Retired Ninja"

Answer (score 0):

set your minimum SDK to lower version in gradle

Comment: In my manifest file my minSdkVersion is set to 19 ( <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"), which is the lowest version that you can set it to in the unity editor :/